# adding btcpay as a payment processor

Tags: payment, plugin

Is there a simple way to add btcpay as a payment processor? They have the same api structure as bitpay, and there is a plugin for that. But Is hardcoded to bitpay, and would need to be changed to work with btcpay.

I tried making this an issue on github, https://github.com/nickcalyx/Bitpay-for-Civicrm/issues but they just wanted me to pay them. understandable, but I dont have a budget for this project yet, thats why i'm trying to setup crowdfunding.

Comment: If the API is identical, couldn't you just change the hard coding on your local copy?

Comment: If I am understanding the documentation right, yes. The problem is I dont know how to do that properly. I had to do some reasrch into how to do this (I'm pretty new to bash/git) but I forked that repo and used sed to replace all the hard coded bitpay.com urls with the url for our btcpay server, then uploaded it our wordpress, but even then still did not work. Spat out the same errors. 

I suspect its because I need to put a port number in there somwhere, or maybe it was expecting some javascript from bitpay.com that our server does not have at the same url.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new [BTCPay extension for CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/extensions/btcpay-payments-civicrm).  [Source](https://github.com/rukykf/btcpay)